# Generate IMG src data URI for SVG with `<use>` elements

Tags: css, svg, shadow-dom

Are there security reasons that prevent `<use>` elements from working in data URI images? I tried something like this:

```js
const svg = document.querySelector("svg");
const img = document.querySelector("img");
img.src = "data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8," + encodeURI(svg.outerHTML);
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <rect id="foo" width="100" height="100"/>
  <use xlink:href="#foo" x="10" y="10"/>
</svg>
<img src=""/>
```

Both Chrome and Firefox give error messages like this if I access the data URI directly:

[image]
[image]

Example of broken image with `<use>` element in data URI:

```html
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20xmlns:xlink=%22http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink%22%20width=%22110%22%20height=%22110%22%3E%0A%20%20%3Crect%20id=%22foo%22%20width=%22100%22%20height=%22100%22/%3E%0A%20%20%3Cuse%20xlink:href=%22#foo%22%20x=%2210%22%20y=%2210%22/%3E%0A%3C/svg%3E%0A"/>
```

Comment: The final <img> example would seem to work for me in Firefox if you add height and width attributes to the <svg> element.

Comment: @RobertLongson Interesting – that's not the case for me. I updated the example.

Comment: Something is odd about your URL encoding. If I decode it via https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ and then reencode it on that site, it works.

Comment: @RobertLongson I just used `encodeURI()` in JavaScript, but I now realize that the `#` has to be escaped separately, as pointed out by @danny-365csi-engelman.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In modern browsers you don't have to escape **<** and **>** in SVG data URI any longer.

Neither is the outdated `xlink` notation required.

But **#** **must** be escaped with **%23**

And for string handling it is easier to use single quotes

That makes the correct **string**:

```
data:image/svg+xml,
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' 
     viewBox='0 0 96 96'>
<rect id='USED' width='50%' height='50%' stroke='red'/>
<use href='%23USED' x='24' y='24'/>
</svg>
```

```html
<style>
 rect{
  fill:blue !important; /* would work for INline SVG, not for data URI SVG */
 }
 img {
   width:200px;
   filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px gold);
 }
</style>
<img src="data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 96 96'><rect id='USED' width='50%' height='50%' stroke='red'/><use href='%23USED' x='24' y='24'/></svg>">
```

#### Notes:

- IMG src places the SVG in a (internal) shadowRoot, so you can't apply CSS anymore
- The image remains an SVG, handled by the SVG parser, so all SVG applies... yes, you can add SMIL animations
- It is a good way to get rid of (bloated) IconFonts
  https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/its-2019-lets-end-the-debate-on-icon-fonts-vs-svg-icons/
- and since you tagged your question `WebComponent`, see: https://IconMeister.github.io