# How to use a SVG in a css file?

Tags: html, css, svg

I was wondering if it is possible to add the SVG code to a CSS file and use HTMl to call it. I mean something like:

HTML:

```
   <div class="svg_gift"></div>
```

CSS:

```
  .svg_gift:<svg viewBox="0 0 40 40"><path class="st0" d="M38.1,10.6h-9.9c1.2-1,2-2.5,2-4.2c0-3-2.4-5.4-5.4-5.4c-2.4,0-4.5,1.6-5.2,3.8c-0.8-1-2-1.6-3.4-1.6c-2.4,0-4.3,1.9-4.3,4.3c0,1.2,0.5,2.3,1.3,3.1H1.9c-1,0-1.8,0.8-1.8,1.8V16c0,1,0.8,1.8,1.8,1.8v18.7c0,1,0.8,1.8,1.8,1.8h14.6h3.3h14.6c1,0,1.8-0.8,1.8-1.8V17.8c1,0,1.8-0.8,1.8-1.8v-3.6C39.9,11.4,39.1,10.6,38.1,10.6z M20.6,6.4c0-2.3,1.9-4.2,4.2-4.2c2.3,0,4.2,1.9,4.2,4.2c0,2.3-1.9,4.2-4.2,4.2h-3.2h-1V7.5V6.4z M21,16.6h-2.1v-4.8H20H21V16.6z M13.2,7.5c0-1.7,1.4-3.1,3.1-3.1c1.7,0,3.1,1.4,3.1,3.1v3.1h-1.1h-2.1C14.6,10.6,13.2,9.2,13.2,7.5z M1.3,16v-3.6c0-0.3,0.3-0.6,0.6-0.6h14.4h1.5v4.8H2.5H1.9C1.6,16.6,1.3,16.4,1.3,16z M3.1,36.5V17.8h14.6v19.3h-14C3.4,37.1,3.1,36.8,3.1,36.5z M18.9,37.1V17.8H21v19.3H18.9z M36.9,36.5c0,0.3-0.3,0.6-0.6,0.6h-14V17.8h14.6V36.5z M38.7,16c0,0.3-0.3,0.6-0.6,0.6h-0.6H22.3v-4.8h2.6h13.3c0.3,0,0.6,0.3,0.6,0.6V16z"/></svg>
```

Comment: use this [tool](https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/) it will convert your `svg` to data-image which you can use as `background-image` or `content: url("the code it will give you")`.

Comment: Also check out this Dev.To article, it loads external SVG : https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd

Comment: And see this SO post on SVG DataURIs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63719564/generate-img-src-data-uri-for-svg-with-use-elements

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are [several ways](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/) that you can include and display SVG files. You can use SVG in CSS as `background-image`.

### Including external SVG file in CSS

The easiest way to display SVG in CSS is by saving the SVG as a separate file and using it as a background in CSS as below.

```
.svg_gift{
    background-image: url(your-path-to-svg.svg);
}
```

Check out this snippet

```css
.svg_gift{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url(https://placeholder.pics/svg/300);
}
```

```html
<div class="svg_gift"></div>
```

[**Refer more here**](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/#using-svg-as-a-background-image)

---

### Including the SVG directly in CSS

As [@Kunal Tanwar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15748278/kunal-tanwar) mentioned in the comments SVG code can be encoded to data-uri via [SVG URL Encoder](https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/) and similar tools. Paste your SVG code and you can simply grab the CSS code to be used.

Here is an example.

```css
.svg_gift{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 40 40'%3E%3Cpath class='st0' d='M38.1,10.6h-9.9c1.2-1,2-2.5,2-4.2c0-3-2.4-5.4-5.4-5.4c-2.4,0-4.5,1.6-5.2,3.8c-0.8-1-2-1.6-3.4-1.6c-2.4,0-4.3,1.9-4.3,4.3c0,1.2,0.5,2.3,1.3,3.1H1.9c-1,0-1.8,0.8-1.8,1.8V16c0,1,0.8,1.8,1.8,1.8v18.7c0,1,0.8,1.8,1.8,1.8h14.6h3.3h14.6c1,0,1.8-0.8,1.8-1.8V17.8c1,0,1.8-0.8,1.8-1.8v-3.6C39.9,11.4,39.1,10.6,38.1,10.6z M20.6,6.4c0-2.3,1.9-4.2,4.2-4.2c2.3,0,4.2,1.9,4.2,4.2c0,2.3-1.9,4.2-4.2,4.2h-3.2h-1V7.5V6.4z M21,16.6h-2.1v-4.8H20H21V16.6z M13.2,7.5c0-1.7,1.4-3.1,3.1-3.1c1.7,0,3.1,1.4,3.1,3.1v3.1h-1.1h-2.1C14.6,10.6,13.2,9.2,13.2,7.5z M1.3,16v-3.6c0-0.3,0.3-0.6,0.6-0.6h14.4h1.5v4.8H2.5H1.9C1.6,16.6,1.3,16.4,1.3,16z M3.1,36.5V17.8h14.6v19.3h-14C3.4,37.1,3.1,36.8,3.1,36.5z M18.9,37.1V17.8H21v19.3H18.9z M36.9,36.5c0,0.3-0.3,0.6-0.6,0.6h-14V17.8h14.6V36.5z M38.7,16c0,0.3-0.3,0.6-0.6,0.6h-0.6H22.3v-4.8h2.6h13.3c0.3,0,0.6,0.3,0.6,0.6V16z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

```html
<div class="svg_gift"></div>
```

Comment: Add CSS "display: inline-block;" this will also work with <i> or <span>